# Promises, I have some trouble getting the return of another function

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a canvas that I want to download as PNG as an image, I got that to work but I want to have my user to choose the name of the file.

I tried to get him to write name of the file with a promise. But my question is, can't I create a function where he asks the name of the file to the user and when it return the name the download begins?
Here is my code:

```
function downloadAsPNG() {
  //Download the image
  let image = new Image();
  image.src = document.getElementById("defaultCanvas0").toDataURL("image/png");
  new Promise(function(nameOfFile) {
    nameOfFile(askNameOfFile());
  }).then(function(result) {
    let nameFile = result + ".png";
    document.getElementById("downloadPNG").download = nameFile;
    return document.getElementById("downloadPNG").href = image['attributes']['src']['nodeValue'];
  });
}
```

Here is the function that I want to call to know the name of the file:

```
function askNameOfFile() {
  let nameOfFile = '';
  let inputNameHTML = "<form id='FormFileName'><input type='text' id='nameOfFile'><input type='submit' id='sendNameOfFile'></form>";
  document.getElementById('NameOfFileContainer').innerHTML = inputNameHTML;
  document.getElementById('FormFileName').addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    nameOfFile = event.target.childNodes[0].value;
    return nameOfFile;
  });
}
```

I know that instead of using a second function I could simply write what I have in the promise but I want to use that function I other function for example upload the file to the server or download as JPEG.

Comment: You can't return a value from an event handler. `askNameOfFile()` doesn't wait for the user to fill in the input.

Comment: `askNameOfFile` needs to be written as an async function that resolves with the name of the file that's selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try askNameOfFile() to return a promise, like so:

```js
function downloadAsPNG() {
  askNameOfFile().then(function(result) {
    console.log('result ==> ' , result);
  });
}


function askNameOfFile() {
let nameOfFile = '';
let inputNameHTML = "<form id='FormFileName'><input type='text' id='nameOfFile'><input type='submit' id='sendNameOfFile'></form>";
document.getElementById('NameOfFileContainer').innerHTML = inputNameHTML;

return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
  document.getElementById('FormFileName').addEventListener('submit',      function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    nameOfFile = event.target.childNodes[0].value;
    resolve(nameOfFile);
  });




});
  

}
```

```html
<button onclick="downloadAsPNG()">Ask for File Name asdf</button>

<div id="NameOfFileContainer"></div>
```